# Page updates appear in Preview but not live version?

Tags: posts, cache, blog, blog-page

I have made some changes to a blog page and excluded some categories. However, whenever I view the blog online the excluded posts still appear. But when I got to the blog page and click 'preview' the excluded categories do not appear, as I wanted.

I have cleared my browsers cache but this does nothing. There are no cache plugins in use.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Test Site: http://crankit.com.au/~dentalwe/blog/

```
function genesis_do_loop() {

    if ( is_page_template( 'page_blog.php' ) ) {
        $include = genesis_get_option( 'blog_cat' );
        $exclude = genesis_get_option( 'blog_cat_exclude' ) ? explode( ',', str_replace( ' ', '', genesis_get_option( 'blog_cat_exclude' ) ) ) : '';
        $paged   = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        //* Easter Egg
        $query_args = wp_parse_args(
            genesis_get_custom_field( 'query_args' ),
            array(
                'cat'              => $include,
                'category__not_in' => $exclude,
                'showposts'        => genesis_get_option( 'blog_cat_num' ),
                'paged'            => $paged,
            )
        );

        genesis_custom_loop( $query_args );
    } else {
        genesis_standard_loop();
    }

}
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "blog page" and "excluded some categories"?

Comment: @Rarst I have a page that I use for displaying my posts. Currently it displays all post categories, however I want to limit it to just 1 post category.

Comment: What _is_ that page? Is it using custom page template? Something else? Please add relevant code the the question.

Comment: @Rarst I have added above. It is using the Genesis framework which uses the above loop on a page_blog.php file

Comment: Please note that commercial products without code publicly available are [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, button 'Preview Changes' displays changes made on post/page while you 'Update' page/post (save changes).

But, 'View Page' displays page as is with latest 'Update' version. So, if you did not updated page, then you'll not see what you get when you go to 'Preview Changes'.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. However, the changes still do not appear after I Update either - they only ever appear in preview mode.

Comment: Can you give some more info? Site/page URL, some screenshot, what theme you use for blog page, maybe some code if you have, do you use regular WP blog archive or some tweak?

Comment: I am using the Genesis framework and a custom theme (someone else built) I have added a link and the example of the loop involved above.